# Failed to enable Hyperloop

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

Using a Pro account, I created a new app (using Studio), when tried to enable Hyperloop, the popup of progress just disappear without any message and still hyperloop disabled.

After checking the Studio logs, I found an error and a suggestion of using the CLI for that.

```
!ENTRY com.aptana.core 1 0 2016-07-18 20:00:53.309
!MESSAGE (Build 4.7.0.201607130543) [INFO] com.aptana.core/debug/shell/output Process Output:
Failed to enable Hyperloop: Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
Unable to register the new app with Appcelerator Platform either due to limited connectivity or other unexpected problem. Please retry later using the command 'appc new --import --project-dir /path/to/project' { [Error: ArrowDB apps already exist for this app_guid]
  success: false,
  description: 'ArrowDB apps already exist for this app_guid',
  code: 400,
  internalCode: undefined }
```

When I tried the `appc new --import --project-dir .`, I got the same message, even removing the app from the platform I can't get hyperloop to work, the other ArrowDB don't seem to have an error (I don't use that personally).

Anything missing?

```
appc -v = 5.4.0-31
appc ti sdk = 5.4.0.v20160712013704
```

Comment: have you tried changing `guid` in `tiapp`?

Comment: @RenePot yep, already tried, I actually made a workaround on this, I activated the logs `--log-level trace` in the command, and it gives me the latest hyperloop url, so I just downloaded from there and made a manual installation, not fancy but works.